# Can $A \subset B$, $x \in A$ imply $d(x, B^c) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let $(X, d)$ be a metric space and assume that $A, B \subset X$ such that $A \subset B$ (strict inclusion). Let $x \in A$. Can it be the case that
$$
d(x ,B^c) = \inf_{ y \in B^c} d (x ,y) = 0?
$$
For any $y \in B^c$, we can take some $z \in B \setminus A$ and use the triangle inequality to get
$$
d( x, y) \leq d( x, z) + d(z, y),
$$
then
$$
\inf_{ y \in B^c} d ( x, y ) \leq d ( x, z) + d(z, y)
$$
and
$$
\inf_{ y \in B^c} d ( x, y ) \leq d (x ,z ) + \inf_{ y \in B^c} d (z, y),
$$
which shows that
$$
0 \leq d (x, z) + d(z, B^c).
$$
Is this any helpful?

Comment: are you just looking for a specific example?

Comment: If it can be the case that $d(x, B^c) = 0$, then an example would suffice.

Comment: The set $A$ doesn't add to the problem at all. $x \in A \subset B$ could just say $x \in B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $X = \Bbb{R}$, with the metric induced by absolute value (i.e the standard one). Let $B = [0,1]$ and let $A= [0,1)$. So, we have a strict inclusion as you want.

If you choose $x=0$, then $x \in A \subset B$, but $d(x, B^c) = \inf_{y \notin [0,1]} |y-x| =  \inf_{y \notin [0,1]} |y|= 0$.

However, if you choose $x = 1/2$ say, then $d(x,B^c) > 0$.

Comment: Also I want to add that $d(x,B^c)> 0$ for all $x \in A$ iff there exist an open $U$ s.t. $A \subset U \subset B$.

Comment: @Matsmir do you have a reference for that result?

Comment: @Holden I'm pretty sure it follows in a few lines by applying the definitions of "open set" and what it means to take infimum

Comment: @Holden Proof goes in the following way. If $A \subset U \subset B$ for some open $U$ then $U^c$ is closed and therefore $d(x,B) \ge d(x,U^c) > 0$ for all $x \in A$. Now suppose that $d(x,B^c) > 0$ for all $x \in A$. Then $d(x,\overline{B^c}) = d(x,B^c) > 0$ and thererfore $A \subset U \subset B$ where $U = (\overline{B^c})^c$.

Comment: Here I used two standard facts. First one says that $d(x,A) > 0$ iff $x \notin \overline{A}$. Second one says that $d(x,A) = d(x,\overline{A})$. $A$ is a subset in some metric space.

Comment: Thank you. In the meantime I tried to show that $d (x, B^c) > 0$ if $A$ is open. Note that $d (x, B^c) = \inf_{ y \in B^c } d ( x, y) = 0$ $\iff$ for every $\varepsilon >0$ there is some $y \in B^c$ such that $d ( x, y ) < \varepsilon \iff y \in D_{ \varepsilon } ( x )$ (open ball with center $x$ and radius $\varepsilon$). Now, if $x \in A$, there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $D_{ \varepsilon } (x) \subset A$; then $d (x, B^c) > 0$, as otherwise $\exists y \in B^c$ such that $y \in D_{\varepsilon}(x) \subset A \subset B$, which is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample:  Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $d$ be the Euclidean metric.  $1 \in \{1\} \subsetneq \{1,2\}$ and $d(1,\{1,2\}^c) = 0$.  More generally, $A \subsetneq B$ allows $A$ to contain points on the boundary of $B$.  For instance, as long as neither $\mathrm{int} B$ nor $B \cap \partial B$ are empty, one could take $A = B \cap \partial B$.

For a  particular metric space, the answer depends on the details of $d$.  For instance, if $d$ induces the discrete topology, then $x$ is a positive distance from every point of $B^c$.

So suppose $x,y \in X$ have the property that for each open neighborhood of $x$ the neighborhood contains a point other than $x$ and the metric $d$ does not induce the discrete topology on that neighborhood and likewise for each open neighborhood of $y$.  Then let $A = \{x\}$, $B = \{x,y\}$.

Comment: Can we get $d(x, B^c) > 0$ if $A$ is (sequentially) compact?  For example, when $A$ is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^d$ with the Euclidean metric?

Comment: @Holden : The $A$ in the counterexample in the first paragraph is closed and bounded in $\Bbb{R}^1$, so positive distance from $B^c$ is not guaranteed by your proposed condition on $A$.